# sql fetch date limit by 1

Tags: php, mysql, date

Instead using time stamp, I am using this one `date('Y-m-d h:i:s A')` and stored as string. My problem is that i can't get the latest value of the date being inserted because I'm using:

> SELECT id, date 
>   FROM table 
>   ORDER_BY date 
>   DESC limit 1

The output is being fetched is `2015-05-28 09:11:16 PM` which is `id = 10` but what I'm trying to fetch is the `id = 12`. Is there a way to compare this values and select the latest one which is id 12?

Table is ordered by date desc

```
| id  |  date                  |
================================
| 12  | 2015-05-28 09:26:20 PM |
| 11  | 2015-05-28 09:26:04 PM |
| 10  | 2015-05-28 09:11:16 PM |
```

Comment: add a `where` clause. I.e. `where id=12` ? trouble understanding the question.

Comment: So do you want the latest that is id 12, or the latest regardless of id?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I need to select only 1 date which is the latest but desc or asc still gets the value date of id=1

Comment: @nik0lias yes the latest date regardless of the id.

Comment: what is the column type for `date`? seems like it's varchar

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using text for its column type

Comment: Ok, well I knew it was text-based, so I was close. Now, if you're early in your project, you'd be better off using MySQL's datetime feature and will be much easier to query later on and for many reasons. You can always modify the "output" with PHP after. Doing it this way, complicates things. Consult https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html and then just do an order/group by with that feature; *way much easier*. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay. thanks mate. I'll try using that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your date column is not of type datetime but varchar. You have to convert it to datetime when sorting:

```
SELECT FROM table
ORDER BY convert(datetime, date, 103) ASC
```

OR with MySQL:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: I've edited my original anwer - please try the or part.

Comment: Ok I see now  your tags says MySQL use the STR_TO_DATE() function      `STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y/%d/%m')`

Comment: *"take out the 'DESC' from your SQL, this will sort the dates ascending"* - As @MarcB stated, you might want to rethink that. From the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html *"The default sort order is ascending, with smallest values first. To sort in reverse (descending) order, add the DESC keyword to the name of the column you are sorting by"*

Comment: ok! ok! i see the `DESC == ascending` thing - edited my answer - Thanks

Comment: I'd call that green ticky, [an assist...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508388/sql-fetch-date-limit-by-1#comment49095646_30508388) ;-) who will win the series this year?

Answer (score 2):

I would `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` This should give you the ID in order from earliest to latest and give you the current record.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could do this way:

```
SELECT id, date FROM table ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) DESC LIMIT 1
```